# Alternative adobe pdf command line print

Tags: command-line, shell-scripting

I need a software like Adobe DC Reader to print pdf file via command line. Actually I use this command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe " /N /S /T /A /O /H "file_name" "printer_name"
```

I need another software because every time I change the printer setting from adobe he remember last settings and not the "default settings"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:

http://www.biopdf.com/guide/print_pdf_from_command_line.php

PDFCMD command="printpdf"

### Additional parameters for printing PDF documents

input                   File name of PDF document to print.
pdfprinter (optional)   Name of PDF printer used for the operation.
printer (optional)      Name of the printer that should receive the print job.
firstpage (optional)    First page to print. Default is the first page.
lastpage (optional)     Last page to print. Default is the last page.
scaletofit (optional)   Scale output to fit (yes|no). Default is yes.
bpp (optional)          Bits per pixel. Valid values are 1, 4, 8, 24 (default).
docname (optional)      Document name in printer queue.
maxdpi (optional)       Maximum DPI resolution to print.
timeout (optional)      Maximum timeout in seconds for the merge
                        to finish. The default is 60 seconds.

Example:
PDFCMD command=printpdf input="C:\Temp\A.pdf"